# Adding Additional Column to Automated Email via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

All -

I'm new to Google Apps Scripting and have cobbled together a script based on some posts around the web. Basically, I've assigned this script to a Google Sheet that collects form responses. With each new submission, a confirmation message is sent to the respondent.

There is an additional column that I've created via script that is not part of the form. I'd also like this column to be sent as part of the confirmation email, but am having trouble getting it added.  In this case, it is column 'AC' or column 29.  Below is the script I've been toying with... can someone offer some guidance as to how to add the data from column AC (#29) to the bottom of my message?

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
function SendConfirmationMail(e) {

try {

    var ss, cc, sendername, subject, columns;
    var message, value, textbody, sender;

    // This is your email address and you will be in the CC
    cc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    // This will show up as the sender's name
    sendername = "My Name";

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
    subject = "Submission Confirmation";

    // This is the body of the auto-reply
    message = "Below are your selections:<br><br>";

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    columns = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // This is the submitter's email address
    sender = e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString();

    // Only include form values that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
        var key = columns[keys];
        if ( e.namedValues[key] ) {
            message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br />"; 
        }
    }

    textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");

    GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                        {cc: cc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});

} catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A minor starting point

Just on following standard, usually the variable `ss` stands for spreadsheet and you derive a variable `sheet` from that, like such:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

A small point but could help readability and avoid confusion for yourself/anyone else using it.

As for getting column AC data, why not try the getRange method you have used previously:

`var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, column, numRows).getValues();`

where `startRow` is the first row of data in the column AC, `column` is the number 29 for the 29th column, and `numRows` is the number of rows of data you want from column AC.

Lets say you want 10 rows from column 29 starting from row 1.

`var data = sheet.getRange(1, 29, 10).getValues();`

You can then simply append it to your message body like so:

`GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody +`**column29Data**`, 
                        {cc: cc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});`

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: I think I've I've ordered the functions or triggers incorrectly. I'm creating an extra column for all my form submissions, which is a link for the user to edit his/her entry. The email script returns an undefined value. My triggers are arranged as follows... is there a way to nest them?
  
ScriptApp.newTrigger("assignEditUrls")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
 
ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendConfirmationMail")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pulling the column values using `e.namedValues`, but this will only be populated with the fields and values submitted through the form. Instead, ready these values directly from the spreadsheet, using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow()` to determine which row is being processed.